# regex: replace matches with their ids

Tags: python, regex

I'm having this situation and I'm wondering if i could do it with regex:

I have a string in this format:

```
{{We all}} love {{stackoverflow}}.
```

My question is how can I use regex replace to get:

```
match1 love match2
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Assuming that there are no other curly braces outside of the items that you want to replace, this should be a simple matter. Pick up a regex tutorial or two and look at some documentation.

Comment: I'm using Python. Will try looking at some tutorial as suggested :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s = '{{We all}} love {{stackoverflow}}.' #string to match
pat = re.compile(r'\{\{.*?\}\}') #pattern
#now replace each matched group by its index
for index,group in enumerate(re.findall(pat,s)):
    s = re.sub(group, 'match'+str(index+1), s)
```

Works for any number of groups.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
result = re.sub("([{]{2}[^}]+[}]{2})([^{]+)([{]{2}[^}]+[}]{2})", r"match1\2match2", subject)
```

**explanation**

```
"""
(          # Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   [{]        # Match the character “{”
      {2}        # Exactly 2 times
   [^}]       # Match any character that is NOT a “}”
      +          # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   [}]        # Match the character “}”
      {2}        # Exactly 2 times
)
(          # Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 2
   [^{]       # Match any character that is NOT a “{”
      +          # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)
(          # Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 3
   [{]        # Match the character “{”
      {2}        # Exactly 2 times
   [^}]       # Match any character that is NOT a “}”
      +          # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   [}]        # Match the character “}”
      {2}        # Exactly 2 times
)
"""
```